# VBA Code for changing background text for any text within a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm trying to make a row change colour to yellow based on if any text is within the D column. I have already set up 5 different colours for another cell, however need this to over-ride those ones. I can make this work if I say ‘YES’ as it’s a pre-determined value. However, I need to input various text and numbers so that doesn’t surfice.

Below is what I have currently gathered but need to change the ‘YES’ so its any text within that cell.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Set MyPlage = Range("T8:T1000") 
For Each Cell In MyPlage
        Select Case Cell.Value  
     Case Is = "Cancelled"
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
     Case Is = "Rejected"
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3           
    Case Is = "Completed"
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Is = "Pending"
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15          
    Case Is = "Accepted"
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    Case Else
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    End Select

Next

 Set MyPlage = Range("D8:D1000")
 For Each Cell In MyPlage
        Select Case Cell.Value
     Case Is = "YES"
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    End Select
Next
```

End Sub

Thanks 
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you don't want to do a select case just check if the cell is empty

Sub run()

```
 Set myplage = Range("D8:D1000")
 For Each cell In myplage
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next
```